# HP Officejet Pro 8600 prints or scans only 1 page under Linux Mint

Tags: linux, printing, printer, linux-mint

My HP Officejet Pro 8600 only scans or prints a single page after that the system says that the connection to the printer cant be established.
If I restart the printer I can print or scan another pager.
Im running Linux Mint 17.1 and the printer is connected over the network